# Override abstract class Sender class in magento 2.1.4

Tags: magento-2.1, resource-model, send-mail

I am trying to set runtime **Email Invoice template** base on custom rule in magento 2.
So I am trying to override class below:
**Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender**
But above class is **abstract classs** with protected method. so I am not able to override same class with method.

I have followed below steps 
1. made entry in **di.xml** like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Custom\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender" type="Custom\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender" />

</config>
```

**2. Sender model class: Custom\Sales\Model\Order\Email\sender.php**

```
<?php

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     * Description of Sender
     *
     * @author Pramod Kharade
     */
    namespace Custom\Sales\Model\Order\Email;

    //use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    //use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface;
    //use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
    //use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;

    class Sender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory
         */
        protected $senderBuilderFactory;

        /**
         * @var Template
         */
        protected $templateContainer;

        /**
         * @var IdentityInterface
         */
        protected $identityContainer;

        /**
         * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
         */
        protected $logger;

        /**
         * @var Renderer
         */
        protected $addressRenderer;

        protected $invoiceruletemp;

        /**
         * @param Template $templateContainer
         * @param IdentityInterface $identityContainer
         * @param SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
         * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
         */
        public function __construct(
            Template $templateContainer,
            IdentityInterface $identityContainer,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
    //            \Custom\InvoiceTemplateEngine\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection $invoiceruletemp,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            Renderer $addressRenderer
        ) {
    //        $this->invoiceruletemp = $invoiceruletemp;
            $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;
            $this->identityContainer = $identityContainer;
            $this->senderBuilderFactory = $senderBuilderFactory;
            $this->logger = $logger;
            $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        }

        /**
         * @param Order $order
         * @return bool
         */
        protected function checkAndSend(Order $order)
        {
            $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());
            if (!$this->identityContainer->isEnabled()) {
                return false;
            }
            $this->prepareTemplate($order);

            /** @var SenderBuilder $sender */
            $sender = $this->getSender();

            try {
                $sender->send();
                $sender->sendCopyTo();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            }

            return true;
        }

        /**
         * @param Order $order
         * @return void
         */
        protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
        {
            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateOptions($this->getTemplateOptions());

    //           $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    //$invoicerule = $objectManager->create('Custom\InvoiceTemplateEngine\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection')->getCollection();
    /** Apply filters here */
    //            echo "<pre>";
    //            print_r(get_class_methods($invoicerule)); die;
    //            foreach ($invoicerule as $key => $val){
    //            print_r($val);    
    //            }
    //             die;
            if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
                $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId();
                $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
            } else {
                $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
             //echo $templateId." Template ID Custom"; die();

                $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            }

            $this->identityContainer->setCustomerName($customerName);
            $this->identityContainer->setCustomerEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
            //$templateId= 4;
            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        }

        /**
         * @return Sender
         */
        protected function getSender()
        {
            return $this->senderBuilderFactory->create(
                [
                    'templateContainer' => $this->templateContainer,
                    'identityContainer' => $this->identityContainer,
                ]
            );
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        protected function getTemplateOptions()
        {
            return [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getStoreId()
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @param Order $order
         * @return string|null
         */
        protected function getFormattedShippingAddress($order)
        {
            return $order->getIsVirtual()
                ? null
                : $this->addressRenderer->format($order->getShippingAddress(), 'html');
        }

        /**
         * @param Order $order
         * @return string|null
         */
        protected function getFormattedBillingAddress($order)
        {
            return $this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'html');
        }
    }
```

Thanks In advance!

Comment: Did you try override using plugin ?

Comment: Yes but not got success

Comment: You can override a method who calls this private method if the calling method is public.

Comment: @sejal Shah Could you please post and below? I had tried by overriding class using preference. But not able getting call to override class.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not override a protected function in an abstract class, either using preference or plugin.**

Like others have mentioned, you have to override the function in the derivative class.

**Only Public Function overrided.**